# What is a good piece of software to plot an affine plane

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I want to plot an affine plane similar to the style of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)#/media/File:Hesse_configuration.svg

Up until now I have been using Goegebra but I have no way of plotting the lines that reach around the ones in the middle.

Comment: There's not really a standard way to do this. I would say the planes of order 2 and 3 are really the only ones that are nicely representable.

Comment: Incidentally, I am just writing a simple parallel line visualization javascript for finite affine planes (so far of order $\le 13$). It's heavily under construction, but you can download or git clone https://github.com/zellerede/Dobble, then open the index.html in your browser from folder *description/projective_planes* (https://github.com/zellerede/Dobble/tree/master/description/proj_planes). Sooner or later, it will be published to a webserver, along with rules of "Dobble passiance".